# Is there still a multi-line tab plugin for kate in kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kubuntu, kate

I'm in love with kate but we have a problem - it drives me mad when I have more than a few files open and only some are displayed on the tab bar. Too see the complete list you have to click on + and open a window, which for me defeats the whole point of the tabs. I can use the Documents plugin which shows a list of open files on the left, but I use a portable monitor in portrait orientation and screen width is at a premium.

At https://kate-editor.org/2011/04/25/kates-tab-bar-plugins/ from 2011 there is a discussion of a multi-line tab bar, but it doesn't seem to be listed in the plugins in kubuntu 18.04 kate.

Is the multi-line plugin still available, and if so how do I install it in 18.04?

Comment: I couldn't find any tab-related plugin even in KDE neon which has just been updated to Plasma 5.14 and Kate 18.08.1. The least inconvenient way to look at your tabs in Kubuntu 18.04 maybe to press `Ctrl`+`Tab`. You'll get a dropdown which you can scroll through by keeping `Ctrl` pressed and hitting the `Tab` key till you highlight the document of interest.

Comment: @DK Bose: thank you, I'm amazed nobody else seems to find this irksome, especially as a multi-tab plugin (used to) exist.